# handlebars list all values into each

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Using [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) want to list all values from a key for each parent key, in my case **tabs**

JSON:

```
{
  "Default":{
    "tabs": [{
      "name":"About",
      "tag":"[[ABOUT]]"
    },{
      "name":"Contact",
      "tag":"[[CONTACT]]"
    }]
  }
}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{{#tabs}}
<div class="box">
  <input id="tab{{@index}}" type="radio" name="tabs" {{#if @first}}checked{{/if}} />
  <div class="tabNames">
    {{#each name}}
    <label for="tab{{@index}}">{{@name}}<i></i></label>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  <section id="content{{@index}}">{{tag}}</section>
</div>
{{/tabs}}
```

I need this output:

```
<div class="box">
    <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked />
    <div class="tabNames">
        <label for="tab1">About</label>
        <label for="tab2">Contact</label>
    </div>
    <section id="content1">[[ABOUT]]</section>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" />
    <div class="tabNames">
        <label for="tab1">About</label>
        <label for="tab2">Contact</label>
    </div>
    <section id="content2">[[CONTACT]]</section>
</div>
```

The problem is on **#each name**.

**Right now is returning only 1 x label and I need all of them.**

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `#each` over a non-collection value like name (string). `#each` is for iterating over an array or the properties of an object. You do not have a collection of names to iterate over. You have an array of "tab" objects, each with a "name" property. Since you are already in the context of an element of the `tabs` array where you want to list all tab names, you will need to use a [Handlebars path](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) to get the `tabs` array from the parent context:

```
{{#each ../tabs}}
    <label for="tab{{@index}}">{{name}}<i></i></label>
{{/each}}
```

Note that you do not access a property like `{{@name}}`, but, rather, like `{{name}}`.

Also, in your example, all of your index start at 1 (`tab1`, `tab2`). Arrays are 0-indexed, so you should expect your output to be 0-indexed as well: `tab0`, `tab1`, etc.